# Looking for an alternative solution for set Interval (Salesforce Lightning Aura component)

Tags: salesforce, salesforce-lightning, salesforce-communities

We have build an component on the Case Lightning Page to highlight dynamically the Case tab after an conditional update on the case record. We also want to use an Case Timer(appExchangeStore) to track the total time spent on the case.

We identified a problem in the Case Timer app caused by the interval in my controller. The timer starts automatically, but when we switch in different tabs it doesn't work correctly anymore.

by that, we are looking for another solution to replace the interval. Any ideas?

Component:

```
<aura:component implements="flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes,flexipage:availableForRecordHome,force:hasRecordId" access="global">
     
    <!--Attributes-->
    <aura:attribute name="CaseFields" type="Case"/>
    
    <!--Component Start-->


    <!--Lightning Workspace API-->
    <lightning:workspaceAPI aura:id="workspace"/>
     
    <force:recordData aura:id="accRecordData"
                      fields="Status"
                      layoutType="FULL"
                      recordId="{!v.recordId}"
                      targetFields="{!v.CaseFields}"
                      recordUpdated="{!c.handleRecordUpdate}"/>
</aura:component>
```

Controller:

```
({
    handleRecordUpdate: function(component, event, helper) {
        var workspaceAPI = component.find("workspace");
        var caseId = component.get("v.CaseFields.Id");
        
        setInterval(function() {
             var caseStatus = component.get("v.CaseFields.Status");
             if(caseStatus === "Response received"){
                    helper.startHighlight(workspaceAPI, caseId);
             } else if (caseStatus != "Response received"){
                    helper.stopHighlight(workspaceAPI, caseId);
             } 
        }, 2000);
    }
})
```

Helper:

```
({
    startHighlight: function (workspaceAPI, caseId) {
        var tabInfo = workspaceAPI.getTabInfo();
        if(tabInfo != null){
        tabInfo.then(function (response) {
            var tabCaseId = response.recordId;
            var focusedTabId = response.tabId;
            var isTabVisible = false;
                
                if(tabCaseId == caseId){
                    workspaceAPI.setTabHighlighted({
                        tabId: focusedTabId,
                        highlighted: true,
                        options: {
                            pulse: true,
                            state: "success"
                        }
                    });
                    workspaceAPI.setTabIcon({
                        tabId: focusedTabId,
                        icon: "standard:answer_public",
                        iconAlt: "Approval"
                    });           
                }
            });
        }
    },
    
    stopHighlight: function (workspaceAPI, caseId) {
        var tabInfo = workspaceAPI.getTabInfo();
        if(tabInfo != null){
            tabInfo.then(function (response) {
                var tabCaseId = response.recordId;
                var focusedTabId = response.tabId;
                var isTabVisible = false;
                    if(tabCaseId == caseId){
                        workspaceAPI.setTabHighlighted({
                            tabId: focusedTabId,
                            highlighted: false,
                            options: {
                                pulse: true,
                                state: "success"
                            }
                        });
                        workspaceAPI.setTabIcon({
                            tabId: focusedTabId,
                            icon: "standard:case",
                            iconAlt: "Approval"
                        }); 
                    }
            }); 
        }
    }
})
```

I tried to found another solution for the set Interval in my controller, but without success.